# Qual a melhor maneira armazenar os dados de Estado Civil no banco de dados?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Olá, tenho uma dúvida:

Preciso criar um `<select></select>` no HTML para o usuário selecionar seu estado civil. Então, estou utilizando PHP para salvar os dados num banco de dados SQL.

Minha dúvida é se devo diretamente inserir os `<option></option>` no HTML (exemplo: `<option>Solteiro(a)</option>` e etc).

Ou, se devo criar uma tabela no banco de dados chamada `estado_civil`, e inserir nela dados como `id = 1, descricao = "Solteiro(a)"`, capturando estas informações e criando os `<option></option>` dinamicamente através de um loop com o PHP.

Qual seria a melhor forma de se trabalhar neste estado atual de programação em requisitos computacionais, olhando para a análise e engenharia de sistemas?

Obrigado desde já a todos!

Comment: Qual é a chance de você ter que alterar a lista de possíveis estados civis na sua aplicação? Em algum momento precisará cadastrar novos ou remover algum existente?

Comment: @Woss 1. A chance de ter novos estados civis é 0. 2. Não precisarei em nenhum momento cadastrar ou remover estados civis. Então com estas análises eu consigo ter uma ideia e saber se devo ou não manter a tabela no banco de dados?

Comment: Que enorme confiança que a legislação ou outros fatores nunca vão mudar.

Comment: Cuidado com os `Nunca` e os `Sempre`. É melhor se preparar pra tudo que PODE acontecer do que pra tudo que DEVE acontecer

Comment: Sugestão: cadastre o texto mesmo. Dessa forma não precisa ter uma tabela só pra saber quais são os descritivos baseados nos códigos e nem ficar fazendo "de-para". Nesse caso específico é simples, mas em outros casos eu sugeriria associar códigos e, se fosse o caso, ligar em outra tabela "de-para" a fim de pegar a descrição dos itens.

Comment: @Maniero de fato, tanto que no Brasil isso já mudou, o estado "desquitado" não existe mais. Era do artigo 315 do Código Civil de 1916, mas na legislação atual só há possibilidade do divórcio. Sobre o post, acho que só vai atrair material baseado em opinião, pois depende de fatores que são peculiares a cada caso (e os casos genéricos me parece que já existe postagem no site). Como o autor comentou, nesse caso talvez não vá alterar de forma alguma, mas isso não é aplicável em outras situações. Ainda, sobre "análise e engenharia de sistemas", depende da cabeça de quem estiver ministrando o curso.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda pessoal, realmente fica muito a critério de quem está desenvolvendo e analisando o sistema, acredito que em sistemas mais simples seja mais fácil utilizar apenas o texto armazenado. Já em sistemas mais complexos, como do Governo, creio que já seja necessário um polimento maior nesta parte. Acredito que em sistemas mais simples a forma de armazenamento por meio de texto facilita até mesmo para deixar o banco de dados mais enxuto.

Comment: Cria os estados civis em Json e pronto, não usa recursos de banco de dados/processamento e não precisa modificar seu VIEW toda vez que for alterar isso, assim aprende a usar Json em suas aplicações e melhora o modo de pensar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Minha dúvida é se devo diretamente inserir os  no
> HTML (exemplo: Solteiro(a) e etc).
>
> Ou, se devo criar uma tabela no banco de dados chamada estado_civil, e
> inserir nela dados como id = 1, descricao = "Solteiro(a)", capturando
> estas informações e criando os  dinamicamente através
> de um loop com o PHP.

A resposta mais correta, parece ser: Depende, mas defendo que a melhor é a segunda opção, ou seja, **criar uma tabela no banco de dados**.

### Motivos:

**1. Flexibilidade do Software:** Caso seja necessário incluir um novo item, não precisará alterar nada no código, bastará incluir o novo registro no banco de dados, inclusive poderá ter um formulário de manutenção de registro aonde um usuário com permissão para acessar esse cadastro, poderá incluir, alterar ou excluir os registros conforme necessário.

**2. Economiza espaço no banco de dados:** Em vez de guardar um campo com 20 caracteres trilhares de vezes, armazenará apenas o `id` do registro. Se considerar uma tabela com poucos registros pode não fazer diferença, mas em uma tabela com trilhões de registros, faria diferença.

**3. Prevenção de Erros nas informações:** No caso de ser utilizado o texto, sem a tabela, caso mandassem deixar o texto todo em caixa alta e no momento de alterar o código da página, o programador alterasse para `SOLTERO(A)` e passasse um bom tempo até que percebessem o erro ortográfico para fazerem a correção, mas podem pensar, "basta corrigir a página web", porém o erro foi refletido para inúmeros registros, para corrigir seria necessário fazer um `UPDATE` para atualizar todos os registros errados. Precisaria considerar também que alguns bancos de dados são *CaseSensitive*, ou seja, `Solteiro(a)` é diferente de `SOLTEIRO(A)` em uma consulta. Esse mesmo cenário trabalhando com tabela não apresentaria tantos problemas, pois geralmente é utilizado um número como chave primária e em relatórios é oferecida uma caixa de seleção que considerará o `id` como parâmetro e não o texto apresentado na descrição.

**4. É aconselhável que o banco de dados esteja normalizado:** Evita repetições e redundâncias. Haverá o inconveniente de ter que fazer junções nas consultas, porém é o recomendado ao se falar em banco de dados relacional. Alguma pessoas falam em desnormalizar o banco por motivo de desempenho, mas a regra é a normalização e a desnormalização é a exceção. Vale salientar que pode utilizar `view` para simplificar a visualização e consulta das informações.